# Cron и знак процента

Tags: debian, cron, crontab

Пишу в файле `crontab` команду

```
длинная команда $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) продолжение
```

Когда *cron* запускает выполнение, то видит только эту часть

```
длинная команда $(date +
```

все, что после `+` он не видит.

как это можно побороть?

Answer (score 3):

согласно документации (`$ man 5 crontab` или [онлайн](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)) символ процента `%` будет преобразован программой *cron* в символ новой строки.

для того, чтобы этого избежать, надо добавить перед каждым используемым символом `%` символ обратной черты:

```
... $(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S) ...
```

Comment: сделал как вы написали, но не помогло, вот как теперь крон видит команду `/usr/bin/vlc -vvv rtsp://111.222.333.444:554/h264/ch01/main/av_stream --sout=file/ts:/home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/source/recording-$()`

Comment: ну, вообще, в исходном вопросе у вас пробел отсутствовал между именем программы (`date`) и первым аргументом (`+что-то-там`). вероятно, потому в оператор подстановки результата выполнения команды (`$(...)`) ничего и не попадает: нет ведь такой программы `date+что-то-там`

Comment: если я эту команду запущу просто в консоле - все работает

Comment: может я не так что то делаю. мне надо просто что бы при каждом выполнении крона генерировалось новое уникальное название файла

Comment: всё правильно вы делаете. только между именем программы и первым параметром/опцией должен быть пробел. не `программапараметр`, а `программа параметр`. не `date+\%Y...`, а `date +\%Y...`