# Выполнение скрипта каждые 2 часа после определённого времени

Tags: cron

Помогите с составлением условия в *Cron*. Нужно, чтобы скрипт начинал работу с 10 утра и потом включался раз в 2 часа до следующего дня. Из общих настроек я узнал, что таким способом(`0 10 * * *`) можно выполнить в 10 часов утра, а таким (`0 */2 * * *`) раз в два часа. Предположил, что ответ на мой вопрос выглядит так: `0 10/2 * * *`, но потом подумал о том, что это в 5 часов. Поэтому подскажите, как выполнить такое условие? И возможно ли его вообще выполнить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
0 10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /path/to/executed.script
```

По идее, должен ещё сработать вариант:

```
0 10-23/2 * * * /path/to/executed.script
```

Но перед использованием такого варианта, я бы посоветовал протестировать его.

Answer (score 1):

вариант 1:

```
0 */2 * * * if [ $(date +"\%H") -ge 10 ]; then ваша-программа-или-команда; fi
```

вариант 2:

```
0 */2 * * * ваша-программа-или-команда-которая-проверяет-сама-что-сейчас-больше-10-часов
```

---

доп. чтение:

- [Cron и знак процента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670303/178576)
- [`$ man date`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=date)
- [`$ man 5 crontab`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=5&topic=crontab)